# How I can prevent someone execute queries excessively in my database?

Tags: firebase

I assign role to user only to read and write after authenticated in firebase database.
I feel like someone can still login to my database to write and read excessive amount of time to owe me money on Google. 
Only thing I can do seems monitor my database and send alert to my phone and stop server to prevent this.

Is this only way I can do to situation like this, or Is there any good option to solve my concern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop authenticated users who have permission to query from making queries.  What you can do is set up [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) in the Google Cloud console, which should apply to all Firebase products as well.